# How to render multi page PDF from multiple HTML sources using Phantom.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, pdf, phantomjs

I would like to create multi page PDF using Node.JS & Phantom.JS but from multiple HTML files, into one PDF. Is it possible using Phantom ?

Comment: How about merging PDF Files into a single PDF Document ?

Comment: I will try thank yoz